# Migration from 1.6 to 2.1 successfull but no settings migrated

Tags: migration, magento2-migration-tool

Just configured and migrated with the data-migration-tool.

Source: 1.6.0.0, Destination: 2.1

First the settings:

```
bin/magento migrate:settings -vvv /var/www/html/vm2.url.com/vendor/magento/data-migration-tool/etc/ce-to-ce/1.6.0.0/config.xml
[INFO][mode: settings][stage: integrity check][step: Settings Step]: started
[INFO][mode: settings][stage: integrity check][step: Stores Step]: started
[INFO][mode: settings][stage: data migration][step: Settings Step]: started
[INFO][mode: settings][stage: data migration][step: Stores Step]: started
[INFO][mode: settings][stage: volume check][step: Stores Step]: started
[INFO][mode: settings][stage: volume check][step: Stores Step]: Migration completed
```

Seemed to work fine, but when I login I can't see any migrated data.
All settings and everything is just like the default 2.1 installation.
Am I doing anything obviously wrong?

Answer (score 0):

You can check your settings migration from database table **core_config_data** and **store** tables if you have setup multistore or multiwebsite.

Second way is to check your settings related data from admin panel.

```
`Content -> Design -> configuration`
```

Choose your theme and open that page

You have display theme related and basic header footer related settings from here.

You can see here so much settings those are relared to settings migrate.

Comment: I mean .. config isn't being migrated. I know how to recognise migrated settings - the migration just isn't happening it seems like.

Comment: you can check your system -> configuration  settings from magento 1 to stores -> configuration settings in magento 2. you have set some basic configuration for magento 1 those are check inside magento 2 all those changes are available? if available means you have migrate settings succesfully

Comment: Not sure whether you understand me or not.
**NONE** of my settings have been migrated.